# Big O notation's alternative definition

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I know the definition of big O is:

g(n) = O(f(n)) if and only if for some constants c and n0, 
|g(n)| <= c.|f(n)| for all n>n0

All I want to know is why this alternative definition is wrong:

g(n) = O(f(n)) if and only if |g(n)/f(n)| is bounded from above as n → ∞,

I guess it is because f(n) may approach 0 and division by 0 is not defined, but I would like to see an example (I couldn't find any one). Please tell me if I'm on the right path.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your first definition of Big-O is wrong. It should be |g(n)| **<=** c.|f(n)|

Comment: And it also should be "g(n) ∈ O(f(n)) if and only if ..." since O() describes a set of functions.

Comment: ^ Although I have seen it written both ways, this is the correct way.

Comment: What is the domain of these functions? Integers? Real numbers? What do you mean by "bounded from above as n → ∞"?

Comment: @Paul 1 isn't bounded above?

Comment: I corrected the first definition, thanks

Comment: g(n) ∈ O(f(n)) seems more appropiate, but in the book says  g(n) = O(f(n)) and it is supposed to be the same

Comment: they gave me the definition: "g(n) = O(f(n)) if and only if |g(n)/f(n)| is bounded from above as n → ∞" which I'm supposed to show is wrong, I copied it literally, I guess bounded from above means that it has an upper bound

Answer (score 2):

In short, your alternative definition is right for every `f(x)` that is not 0 for every `x>x0` for some `x0`. Checkout the formal definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

---

To see it for ourselves, let's try proving the two definitions are equivalent, and we'll see the special case arising naturally:

If the first definite holds, then there is a `c` and a `n0` as described. To get to the second definition we will want to divide the first definition by `|f(n)|`. To do so we need to assume it is not 0 for any `n>n0` so let's assume that and keep in mind that if the function does evaluate to 0 we need to treat it differently (`|f(n)|=0 <=> f(n)=0`) and there's our special case. Now that we assumed that, we can divide and get `|g(n)/f(n)|<=c<inf`  for `n>n0` which is the second definition.

If on the other hand we start with the second definition, we know that `lim sup (for n->inf) |g(n)/f(x)|<inf'. We can also be sure it exists from the definition as the group of values for the left hand side of the equation is defined and bounded from above (again, assuming`f(n)`dues not equal 0) for`n>n0`for some`n0`. Let's call the limit sup`c`and multiply by`|f(n)|` and we get the first definition.

So all in all they are equivalent for `f(n)`-s that do not equal zero for all `n>n0` for some `n0`.

Comment: You're welcome! If this is the right answer for you - please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)